# QuickBlox. iOS. Returns wrong IDFacebook

Tags: ios, facebook, quickblox

After authorization request returns wrong IDFacebook.

Request returns number ID: "1505276699730028", and should: 100002823...etc

Code:

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {

        [QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" scope:@[@"public_profile"] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {

        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

            NSLog(@"Errot: %@", response);

        }];

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {


    }];
```

Why? Where is error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is the right ID. That is an app scoped user id. To understand what it is I suggest that you read the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog